# how to create a real-time application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

using **jsf2.0 and PrimeFaces 3.0.RC2**, I want to make `<p:dataTable />` that contais my system request and when one user holds a request. i must update the status of this request and updata all the other users' `<p:dataTable />` that they are oping the system.
How can i do that?
[image]

suppose that this screen appears to 10 users and when one changes the status and clicks **Update** button should reflect on the all users' screen.

and if any one added a new model in DB should this appear.

i mean an example like email

Answer (score 0):

The other users cannot passively know (via HTTP) when something's changed server-side. You have to somehow activelly poll the server and update the changes in the UI. You might make a timer that checks ever x seconds, or do it on different browser events (like when the user no longer uses the browser window and then returns to it).

The best thing to do however is just make a refresh button, this way the users will poll for new data only when they really want to, this way you're not over-reading from your database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for so-called `push`, `reverse_ajax` or `comet` techniques. PrimeFaces implements this technology by means of a servlet, but only works on Jetty server. Look at chapter 6 of the User Guide.

Also, have a look at [cometD](http://cometd.org/), a mature project that provides implementations of the Bayeux protocol in javascript and other languages. This project uses Jetty as well, but is portable to other Servlet-3.0-compliant servlet containers. I am running it on GlassFish server without any problem, but on the client side I have a dojo dataGrid instead. You may try to integrate to PrimeFaces dataTable through Javascript, although I have not done it yet, and am not sure whether this is an easy task or not.

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces' push technique works on other servers, for example on Glassfish, too.
A good sample, how to implement it:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/counter.jsf